# How to access external javascript file from the php file

Tags: php, javascript, session-variables

I need to access a javascript function which is in the separate file.

Here is what I am trying to do:

in the php file I have:

```
var session_lang= <?php echo $_SESSION['SESS_LANGUAGE'];?>;
    if (session_lang!='')
    {
        check_and_change(session_lang);
    }
});
```

and I have this `check_and_change()` function in that separate javascript file which is of course included.

One more thing. I am getting error that there is a unknown `<` sign, so probably my php variable can't be read. If someone can please check that too.

Comment: Take a look at *console*. What it say?

Comment: Check if there any php open tag not closed...

Comment: I am getting unexpected token at `<` sign

Comment: Where is the `});` coming from? And what is getting parsed into the HTML output? Maybe an error is getting placed on the variable location causing the `unknown <` error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the error line is the line with the session_lang variable, then you forgot the double qoutes (if the session_lang is a string).

```
var session_lang = "<?php echo $_SESSION['SESS_LANGUAGE'];?>";
    if (session_lang!='')
    {
        check_and_change(session_lang);
    }
```

Comment: Have you considered that `$_SESSION['SESS_LANGUAGE']` might already contain those double quotes?

Comment: No I didn't, would be ugly though to add double qoutes to an variable that is probably used in other (none HTML) functions as well.

Comment: I'm aware of that, just saying, don't say it as if it were 100% correct, it's also possible that he doesn't have PHP enabled at all the the PHP tags are rendered on the page.

Comment: It is not working, now I am getting `unexpected syntax ILLEGAL`

Comment: got it to work. I forgot to put `session_start()`, new problem is that I can access that function which is in the included file

Comment: You mean that you can't call the function in the included file? Are you sure? Is the included js really included (check by checking the source)? If so, then replace all code in the function with a simple `alert` to check if it is called.